# Purge Guake with config files: Preference files survive somewhere

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, uninstall, 19.04, guake

I need to completely remove Guake. It seems to have some bug that I triggered while setting keybindings. Now the "close tab" keybinding does not work anymore. I tried

```
$ sudo apt-get purge guake
$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove guake
```

and different variantions of these. When I reinstall Guake, my old preferences are still there: color scheme etc. I can't locate where the preference files are located though. How can I remove Guake entirely together with the somehow broken preference files?

## edit

I run Kubuntu 19.04

## edit 2

```
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
▶ which guake
/usr/bin/guake

~                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
▶ apt-cache policy guake
guake:
  Installed: 3.4.0-1
  Candidate: 3.4.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 3.4.0-1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

~                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
▶ ls -ld ~/.config/dconf
drwx------ 2 lo-pilno 4096 Sep 21 14:47 /home/lo-pilno/.config/dconf
```

Comment: `~/.config/guake` perhaps? in general, `apt` should **never** mess with user's personal files (including their application preferences)

Comment: @steeldriver I don't have `~/.config/guake`. If it was that obvious I would have found it myself :D I am running KDE (Kubuntu), not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: @N0rbert Kubuntu 19.04

Comment: @N0rbert sure, done.

Comment: @N0rbert Sorry, missed that one. It's there now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98928/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-lo-tolmencre).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods vary on the Ubuntu version:

- On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS the per-user configuration for Guake is stored in

  ```
  ~/.gconf/apps/guake
  ```

  You can remove files from this folder to purge per-user configuration.
- On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and newer versions it uses [`dconf` / `gsettings`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME#Configuration) for configuration. Install `dconf` command with `sudo apt-get install dconf-cli` and then
  reset Guake settings with

  ```
  dconf reset -f /apps/guake/
  ```

  In command above the `/apps` is not a real folder, it is virtual path for configuration scheme (*org.guake.gschema.xml* in [our case](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/all/guake/filelist)). We need to purge whole Guake directory, so the path should end with slash ("`/`").

Then restart Guake or re-login to reapply the settings.

Comment: For future reference: The trailing backslash in `/apps/guake/` is not optional!